# Inline Javascript Variable as Part of an Element Attribute in Slim

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, custom-data-attribute, slim-lang

**Background:**

I am using the [skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) plugin as part of a Rails project that is using Slim for markup.
The plugin requires data attributes for start and end points for scrolling animations. Here is an example:

```
#canvas-1 data-0="top:-80px;" data-1180="top:0px;"
```

The plugin will basically animate the `top` css from `data-0` (scroll position 0px) to `data-1180` (scroll position 1180px).

**Question:**

A few elements on the page that need to be animated are positioned below containers with varying heights. So, the `data-xxxx` can be different depending on the content in the preceding containers. I have a javascript function that figures out the height of all the preceding elements and returns a variable of what the `data-xxxx` should be. This is theoretically what the output should look like in Slim:

```
#logo.unit data-#{ "<script>logoPosition</script>" }="top:5px" data-#{ "<script>logoPosition + 200</script>" }="top:-8px;"
```

Slim errors. No matter how I try to add the inline javascript attribute - it errors. My current solution is all javascript (which replaced the attribute completely). However, I would like to know the proper way of doing inline javascript generated attributes.

Possible?

Comment: Using jQuery you could say `$('#logo.unit').data('1180', 'top: 0px;')` or something?

Comment: Yes, that's what I currently have: `$('element').data(relativePos, 'top:0px;');`. However, I would like to just output the variable in the markup. This would reduce the running js code size by one line per element.

Comment: If you're still looking to do it with JS, it's probably cleaner, more efficient, and more semantic to do it elsewhere. If you want to do it inline like that, maybe a server-side script would suit you better? That, of course, is just my opinion

Comment: Yes, I agree and see what you are saying. I thought about a server side script; however, the problem is that the scrollr animations are done based on scroll position. Depending on monitor sizes and flow of elements, the position needs to be calculated on the client side, once all elements complete loading. This is just one of those situations where all the 'proper' methods were exhausted before moving on to the hacky methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you can do this with skrollr alone. Read the docs about **relative mode** https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#absolute-vs-relative-mode

Like this (you get the idea):

```
#logo.unit data-top="top:5px" data-200-top="top:-8px;"
```

Using `data-anchor-target="#logo.unit"` you could even have the animation of other elements depend on the position of the logo.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that in the docs! It's nice to have Prinzhorn himself pitch in.. Thank you!

Comment: is it possible to have 2 sets of relative data anchors per element? Say the logo needs to move twice during the scroll - after it passes the first section and after it passes the second section?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You can have as many keyframes as you want, but only a single `data-anchor-target`